# How to use Mathematica to solve equations in a polynomial ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, mathematica

I am sorry. But I wonder whether it is fine to ask this question here.

I need some help to solve some equations in a polynomial ring:

Give the ring $\mathbb{F}_p [x ]/(x^2+x+1)$, where $p$ is a prime (for example $p=5$). I need to solve some equations like:

$(1-x)f_i(x)+x f_j(x)-f_k(x)=0$

I have no idea how to solve this in Mathematica. (Of course, we can solve them via pencil and paper. But it is a headache if it involves 20 or more equations.) Any help is appreciated.

My own approach was to set $f_i(x) = a+b x$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_5$. Then try to solve the (linear) equations $mod\  5$. But it failed because we may need $x^2+x+1=0$.

Comment: This question might be better suited at [Mathematica SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of substitutions could help here, `x^2->-x-1`. For arbitrary polynomial `y` with integer coefficients:

```
qFp[y_,p_]:=((y//Expand) //.{x^n_ /;n>1->x^(n-2)(-x-1)//Expand}//Expand) /. a_Integer -> Mod[a, p]
```

Will be an equal to $q(x)$ polynomial in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ of degree 1. For example,

```
qFp[x^5+7x+4,5]
```

gives

```
x+3
```

Comment: +1 Neat. Clearly I don't know enough about Mathematica. When I was learning it, AlgebraicRules was used in contexts like this, but that was clumsy. I need to try this the next time I need it!